# How to get object inside a Future in Scala

Tags: scala, akka

I use Akka myActor1 to ask another myActor2 for a future response like below:

```
val future = myActor2 ? request
val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Person]
```

let's say result is a case class like this:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

I don't want to block the process so I choose not to use Await.result.
Thus I have the below code:

```
val future = (myActor2 ? request).mapTo[Person]
```

now future is Future[Person] and not a Future[Any]. 
how can I then extract the person contained inside the future and handle exception?
I tried something with onComplete but Success seem to only accept Int and not Person. I would like something like below:

```
future onComplete {
   case Success(result) => result
   case Failure(failure => doSomethingOnFailure(failure)
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: when you are communicating between two actors you should never use an ask.
Use a tell then listen to a response message.

Comment: Did you check the `pipe` function? https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html?language=scala#ask-send-and-receive-future

Comment: You cannot and should not extract value from a monadic context, but compose within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the handling of the response to happen by processing another message. If you are okay with considering the response from the other actor a message, it might be enough to simply send the request with `tell` (`!`) and add a case to the receive method for the response.

If you need to avoid confusing parallel requests and responses, you might want to use `become` and `Stash` to make sure only 1 request can be in flight at a time. Do realize that this limits the throughput of your system, of course.

If you want to somehow 'translate' the response before passing it to `receive` handler, the `pipe` pattern might come in handy:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

...
    val someIdentifier = ???
    (myActor2 ? request)
      .map(response => MyCommandWith(response, someIdentifier))
      .pipeTo(self)
```

This will collect the result of the `ask`, map it and then send it as a message to the current actor (`self`). Be very careful not to close over any actor state in the map function though!

If you want further result or error handling to be done by the original sender of the message, you don't need `pipe` at all but you could use `forward` instead of `ask`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic to convert `Future[Person]` into `Person`. You have to either call `Await` on this future to extract the result or make this piece of code return `Future[Smth]` and delegate extraction of the result to a caller.